# Custom ConstraintViolationException in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

How I catch exception for this ConstraintViolationException :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-05-31T07:23:03.419+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [fkitcllv8yn2id9lj3rmw3wskhd]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/pelajar"
}
```

This Excaption is happen, when I try to deleting a record. But that record still used as reference by other record in other table.

I Have 2 CustomExceptionHandle :
 the 1st for catch general exception and 
 the 2nd for catch ConstraintViolation exception.

But in my program, each time ConstraintViolation trigger-up, the handleAllExceptions will be executed.
My expectation is  handleConstraint function should be executed.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
    public  ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraint(ConstraintViolationException ex, 
            WebRequest request ) {

        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), "Record still have reference from other table",
                request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);       
    }


    @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage()+" Custom Error",
                request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

But, If I remove handleAllExceptions the ConstraintViolationException will be catch by handleConstraint function.

Can anyone give me advice ?

Thank You.
Alt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have imported `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` instead of `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` in `CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. Kindly import `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` if not imported correctly.